# How to have two named groups with same name in .net regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am having a regex to identify some named groups. There are a few cases which have multiple groups with different patterns. The problem is to have all named groups into corresponding lists. The constraint is that I cannot have more than one regex and I cannot call execute the regex more than once. I have tried following code, but it always returns second pattern:

```
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"(?<n1>pattern_n1_1) (?<n2>pattern_n2_1) (?<n1>pattern_n1_2) (?<n2>pattern_n1_2)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        String str = "pattern_n1_1 pattern_n2_1 pattern_n1_2 pattern_n1_2";

        List<String> matchedText = new List<string>();
        List<String> string_n1 = new List<string>();
        List<String> string_n2 = new List<string>();

        MatchCollection mc = reg.Matches(str);
        if (mc != null)
        {
            foreach (Match m in mc)
            {
                matchedText.Add(m.Value.Trim());
                string_n1.Add(m.Groups["n1"].Value);
                string_n2.Add(m.Groups["n2"].Value);
            }
        }
```

Here the list `string_n1` and `string_n2` has one element each. `string_n1` has "pattern_n1_2" and `string_n2` has "pattern_n2_2". However, I require both "pattern_n1_1" and "pattern_n1_2" to be in `string_n1` AND both "pattern_n2_1" and "pattern_n2_2" to be in `string_n2`

Comment: not the solution, but I find [this](http://www.regexr.com/) tool very handy when it comes to debugging regex strings. Perhaps it can be of some help to you.

Comment: @NickOtten: Don't suggest regexr on a C# question. It is tool for JS RegExp. For .NET regex, there is regexhero and regexstorm, also regexplanet, though from my experience, regexstorm is the best in displaying the full power of .NET regex.

Comment: There seems to be a typo in your code.  Going by the text of your question, I believe he last token was supposed to be `pattern_n2_2`, not `pattern_n1_2`.  The error is repeated in the corresponding portion of the regex.

Comment: @nhahtdh I will look into the tools suggested Thank you. I used to use debuggex with PCRE engine in this tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to change your regex. You only need to change the way you retrieve the result from the capturing groups.

Since you have multiple capturing groups under the same name, in order to retrieve all captures done under that name, you need to loop through all `Capture` in `Groups["n1"].Captures`, instead of accessing a single capture with `Groups["n1"].Value`.

```
MatchCollection mc = reg.Matches(str);
if (mc != null)
{
    foreach (Match m in mc)
    {
        matchedText.Add(m.Value.Trim());

        foreach (Capture c in m.Groups["n1"].Captures) {
            string_n1.Add(c.Value);
        }

        foreach (Capture c in m.Groups["n2"].Captures) {
            string_n2.Add(c.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

[**Demo on ideone**](http://ideone.com/eSXWSc)

This is a feature, as far as I know, unique to .NET Regex API. None of the other flavors offers an API to go through all matches of a repeated capturing group:

```
^\w+(?: (\w+))+$
```

Other flavors only return the last capture for the capturing group 1 in the above example. .NET allows you to extract all captures by a capturing group.

And although there are flavors allowing you to define the same name for different capturing groups, other flavors only allow you to access to one of the captures when querying via the group name.

### Reference

- [`Group.Captures` property on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. The code is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the specifics, the follow **may** work for your needs, but is not generalized solution:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"((?<n1>(pattern_n1_1|pattern_n1_2)) (?<n2>(pattern_n2_1|pattern_n1_2)) ){2}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This will capture a bit more than the original, in that pattern_n1_2 would be caught as the fourth "group" in this version for example, but not the original.